# Google Apps Script Doc - add Image with Links

Tags: html, svg, google-apps-script, drawing

I need to insert an image with several links into a Google Doc via Google Apps Script. The image is a basic map, created in HTML5, with several hotspots. If displaying this image via my existing application, I would export the image to SVG and use SVG's native hyperlinking. Otherwise I can generate a PNG of the diagram and a map and area tags for the links. For my google apps script, I have no problem in pulling in a PNG of the image and inserting it, but I have no way of adding my link maps. I also cannot find a way to import an SVG (as a Google Drawing) which can be placed inline of the document. Here are the things that I would do to solve this, but I am missing critical pieces of each one, any help on any of the three problems would be greatly appreciated:

1. Generate an SVG of the image and insert it into the Google Doc
   Problem: Google Doc does not accept SVG. Is there a way to make the Doc accept the SVG or is there a converter that will take my SVG and return a Google Drawing that can be inserted?
2. Generate a PNG and insert that into the Google Doc. 
   Problem: No links. Is there a way to define a link map in Google Doc via Google Apps Script?
3. Insert an HTML5 Canvas
   Problem: not possible in Google Docs

Answer (score 3):

Google Docs doesn't support images with hyperlinked sections, therefore Apps Script doesn't either. You can set a link for an entire image using [InlineImage.setLinkUrl()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/inline-image#setLinkUrl%28String%29).

Comment: Thanks Eric, Not even Google Drawings?

Comment: Unfortunately we don't yet have support for manipulating or inserting Google Drawings within Apps Script.

Comment: I had seen this: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/inline-drawing

And assumed that drawings were supported. However, I had difficulty in converting SVG to Google Drawing. I did write a process that went SVG -> WMF -> Google Drawing, but by the time I got to the drawing, I lost the links. When I manually tested adding a native drawing to a doc, it lost it's links as well.

Comment: Before writing Apps Script code it's first worth seeing if what you want is possible at all in the product. Apps Script allows you to automate various activities, but it often faces the same limitations that you'll find in the product's UI.

Answer (score 0):

Google Drawings looks like a no as well. I'm not sure how complex your map is but could you maybe break it into smaller images and link each image separately? I understand its not exactly what you were looking for but maybe an option?